# Insert First 6 Characters after the word Color in textbox

Tags: html, vb.net, converters

Maby they question was kinda hard. so im going to explain it the best i can.

When i have this Code in my Textbox1 "[Color=#000000] [/color]"
i want to Select 5 characters after #
so i get 000000

what im trying to do is simply.

Covert the [color=#000000][/color] into html

heey Found something :).

my code =

```
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text

    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("color=", "<font color=" + DubbelQ)
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("#", myNum + ">")
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("[/color]", "</font>")
```

it Converts [color=#ColorCode][/color] into ColorCode

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code.... could you explain in point form what you are expecting to happen to the #HexValue entered by the user in TextBox1 and the button is clicked.

Comment: I want it to be selected so the output can be <font Color="#HexValue"></font> instead of just <font Color=""></font>

Comment: 5 characters??? 000000 is 6

Comment: is the color being shown on a future page if the user enters it in the text box or is it dynamically changing as the user enters the color in hex?

Comment: well i have the replace code when Text in textbox1 is changed. but whats realy annoying is that i cant get the hex code in the right place so i can also type a word between the closing/opening tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to exactly achieve but.... I don't think you have to select insert or replace....

1. User inputs a hex value in TextBox1
2. User Clicks button.
3. Code on button click will take hex value and ???? at the moment all I can
   assume it is going to output the text in Texbox2 as a html 
   tag

   ```
   Sub button1_click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles button1.click

       Dim outputString as String = "<font color='#" & TextBox1.Text & "'>Test Text</font>"

       TextBox2.Text = outputString

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: well thats not exactly what i want. want im going to do is. paste ubb code in textbox1 then textbo2.text will be textbox1.text then everything is being replaced but the hex value is inside a tag so i need to grab that last 6 letters from # so i can do like + "#" + last 6 letters after that